# How to avoid recomputation in a loop in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How would one efficiently implement something like this in Tensorflow:

```py
expensive_op_graph = expensive_op(input)
for i in some range:
    result = some_op(expensive_op_graph, simple_op_graph)
```

where the simple_op_graph depends on an input that gets fed as a placeholder (different for each iteration). I want to avoid recomputing the expensive_op in each iteration. I've looked into partial_run but it does not seem to work with for loops like that. One workaround is to call session.run() on expensive_op_graph and then store the result for future reuse? Is there any idiomatic way to solve this kind of a problem? I'm using Tensorflow 1.12.0.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question. But basically I do not want to recompute the expensive graph in each iteration but instead want to run it once and then reuse the result in each iteration.

Comment: Yes, doing `sess.run(expensive_op)` once and then running `sess.run(simple_op)` every iteration would be the normal way you'd do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing sess.run(expensive_op) once and then running sess.run(simple_op) every iteration; a comment from @thushv89.